# I have been integrating differential equations for many, many years. How should I justify a certain step in the process though?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Someone with plenty of experience of integrating differential equations, if faced with the simple first order equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dy}{dx}= x \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Might, almost without thinking, write down something like

\begin{equation*}
\int \left\{\frac{dy}{dx}\right\} dx  =  \int x dx \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
y(x)+d=\frac{x^2}{2}+k  \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
y(x)  = \frac{x^2}{2}+ (~k-d~)
\end{equation*}

( some thought may have gone into choosing to use ‘$d$’ on the RHS of **$(3)$**, rather than ‘$c$’ )

They would find
\begin{equation*}
y(x)  = \frac{x^2}{2}+ c~~~~~~~~~\text{where} ~~c=~k-d
\end{equation*}

The solution can be completed by having some extra information about $y(x)$, say $y(0)=a$. From information like this, the value of ‘$c$’ may be determined.

My question is: How can getting from **(2)** to **(3)**, be justified?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to realise is, what’s going on in getting from **(1)** to **(2)** , and hence understanding the meaning of **(2)**. We have

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dy}{dx}= x \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

Note that **(1)** is an equality between two functions of ‘x’, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $f(x)=x$.
As these two functions are equal, they **must** possess the same set of antiderivatives. These sets are

\begin{equation*}
\int \left\{\frac{dy}{dx}\right\} dx = \left\{ y(x)+d\mid d\in\mathbb{R}\right\} \tag{S1}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
~~~~~~~~~~\int x dx=\left\{\frac{x^2}{2}+k\mid k \in\mathbb{R}\right\} \tag{S2}
\end{equation*}

The sets satisfy **(2)**

\begin{equation*}
\int \left\{\frac{dy}{dx}\right\} dx  =  \int x dx \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

On the RHS of **(2)** we have a known set, so that even though, $y(x)$, is as yet unknown, we, by the equality of LHS to RHS, know what the set appearing on the LHS of **(2)** must be.

**Getting From (2) to (3)**

From **(2)**, we may deduce, whatever $y(x)$ ends up being, it will be possible to pick the element ‘$y(x)+d$‘  for some ‘$d$’ from the set $S1$, such that this same mathematical object (a function ) can also be chosen from the set $S2$ ( the element ‘$\frac{x^2}{2}+k$’ for some ‘$k$’ ).

In equation form, we will be able to satisfy the following equation,

\begin{equation*}
y(x)+d=\frac{x^2}{2}+k  \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

for some values of ‘$d$’ and ‘$k$’, even though $y(x)$ is, as yet, unknown.

This is my explanation of how we justify getting from **(2)** to **(3)**.

Comment: maybe it's better to include your understaing in the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching the function $y(x)$, you are looking at a paramatrized curve $(x(t),y(t))$.

By the chain rule it should satisfy $ {dy \over dt}=x.{dx \over dt}$.

Integrating between $t_0,t$, you get $y(t)={x^2\over 2}(t) +C$
Forgetting the parametrization, you see that your curve is contained in a parabola $y={x^2\over 2}+C$